# Oracle inserting into table with composite key

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle12c

I have a table, `TBL_1`, with the following fields:

```
TBL_ID NUMBER (pk),
CREATE_DATE DATE (pk),
TBL_IND VARCHAR2(1)
```

The primary key is on `TBL_ID` and `CREATE_DATE`, I am trying to perform an insert statement but getting an error `ORA-00001: unique constraint (primary key) violated`.

There is a before insert trigger setting the `NEW.CREATE_DATE` as `SYSDATE`. The insert statement looks like:

```
  INSERT INTO TBL_1 (tbl_id,tbl_ind)
  SELECT tbl_id,'Y' 
    FROM tbl_info;
```

The actual query is a little more complex but I just wanted to point out it is a `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement. Is it possible if there is a duplicate `tbl_id` the trigger used the same exact date for both rows thus causing a duplicate error? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to have `create_date` as part of the primary key.  I would suggest that you use a sequence value instead.

If you don't mind reducing the number of rows, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_1 (tbl_id,tbl_ind)
    SELECT DISTINCT tbl_id, 'Y' 
    FROM tbl_info;
```

Or, if you still want all rows inserted, then restructure your data to use a sequence instead of the creation date.